# error "--secure-file-priv option" when save selection to csv

Tags: mysql, permissions

I try to save a very large select (more than 70 milion rows into csv file) on Win 2012 R2 server

I execute query as root , but I think there is still some problem with privileges

```
select * 
INTO OUTFILE 'D:\my_folder\my_file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
from my_table
where 
...
```

Error

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: do a show show variables like 'secure_file_priv'; and give file path in that foldder or turn it off from cnf file and restart instance. You may also need to have write permissions on OS folder to write with MySQL running user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Win2012 I found file my.ini.

In the file there is a definition of secure_file_priv - a folder when I can download to or uplload from ,

So I change my query as following:

```
 SELECT * 
 INTO OUTFILE 'D:\<folder_defined_as_secure_file_priv>\my_file.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 FROM my_table
 WHERE 
 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using MySQL Server 8.0 on Windows 10. I tried to load data from csv file using the following commands:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\World_cup_dataset.csv'
INTO TABLE trial
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

When I run above commands, I got

> "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"

I tried many methods to solve the problem. Finally, I changed the '`\`' characters in the file path to '`/`' characters.

I mean my new file path became `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/World_cup_dataset.csv` and my problem were fixed. If you look at my.ini file located in the MySQL Server folder, the path of `secure-file-priv` is "`C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads`". So, this solution makes sense.

Comment: Oh man I was going crazy, thanks for the tip. Just replace \ by / ;)

Comment: very good to hear it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";

secure_file_priv    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\

SELECT  *  INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/algo.csv'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   FROM sams.trafico;
```

Comment: Would you be able to add a little explanation as to what the commands are doing and how this solves the posters problem?

Answer (score 2):

Following [Mehmet's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227928/22336), for me escaping the "\" character did the trick.

`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\file.csv`

became

`C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\file.csv`

Answer (score 1):

I have also had these issues and did some experimenting, using the different answers I found on the Internet. I have gotten this to work on my local WAMP (3.1.7) server on a Windows 10 63-bit PC. I did this within PHP, logged on as root administrator.

First I simply nullified the `--secure-file-priv` problem by entering  `secure-file-priv = ""` under the `[mysqld]` heading in `my.ini`.

Secondly I created an SQL query and executed it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inloggning INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Temp/sample.csv' CHARACTER SET 'Latin1' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY '\;' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";

$result =   mysqli_query($databas_link, $sql) 
            or die('File output failed!(sql) - MySQL error: ('.mysqli_errno($databas_link).') '.mysqli_error($databas_link).' ');
```

This works perfectly for me. Now I am working on how to save the file on the web hotel server, using the same changes and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want to store the output in a subdirectory to make it easier to manage e.g. `./my_script_data/` inside the secure folder, but you might run this script on multiple servers, possibly with different secure directories.

Firstly, for each server, set the `secure_file_priv` to the most appropriate directory, perhaps on another drive e.g. `X:/mysql_secure`. Do this by modifying the `my.ini` file (**create a backup first**), searching for `secure-file-priv` and providing an absolute path:
`secure-file-priv="X:/mysql_secure"`

**NOTE:** Make sure to save your file in the same encoding that it was originally written in (usually UTF-8). If you do not, the MySQLxx service will not start.

In your SQL script, store your output directory in a variable, using `CONCAT()` to append other file paths as needed (they will have to be created manually before executing, unfortunately). That means the following path must already exist: `X:/mysql_secure/my_script_data/`

To create a timestamped CSV file with your output use the following:

```sql
-- ## VARIABLES
SET @stamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H%i%s');
SELECT CONCAT(@@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv, 'my_script_data/') INTO @outdir;
-- @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv in Windows returns a path with '\'
--  hence our need to replace '\' with '/'
SET @outdir = REPLACE(@outdir, '\\', "/");

-- ## STATEMENT EXECUTION
SET @statement := CONCAT("SELECT * FROM my_database.table WHERE conditions INTO OUTFILE '",@outdir,"my_file_prefix_", @stamp, "_suffix.csv'");
PREPARE extrct FROM @statement;
EXECUTE extrct;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
```

This produces a file: `X:/mysql_secure/my_script_data/my_file_prefix_2021-05-24_190827_suffix.csv`.

I omitted field terminations, enclosures, and line terminations because they were the default values. These could be inserted into the `@statement` variable if needed.

This was tested using Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, both running MySQL 8.0.x.